# Center list-elements horizontally independent of amount of elements

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to center a series of list elements of unknown amount.

[image]
Here's a basic html:

```
<ul>
 <li>item 1</li>
 <li>item 2</li>
 <li>item 3</li>
 <li>item 4</li>
 <li>item 5</li>
 </ul>

 <ul>
 <li>item 1</li>
 <li>item 2</li>
 <li>item 3</li>
 <li>item 4</li>
 </ul>
```

And CSS:

```
 ul {
  width: 100%;
 }

li {
   list-style: none;
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

And a JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ea37r9mr/

Comment: /me looks at image. centered?

Comment: @PeeHaa Yes entered.

Comment: Your li's are neither horizontally entered nor centered in the image.

Comment: add text-align: center to your ul tag, It will done

Answer (score 2):

Add `text-align:center;` in your `ul`

```css
ul {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #222222;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  width:10%;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  border: 2px solid #222222;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the JSfiddle that you provided, all you need to do is add `text-align: center` to your `ul` element.

Like so:

```
ul {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
    text-align: center;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1em;
}
```

Here is your [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qyevkzrh/) that I have edited with the `text-align` added so you can visually see the change.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The classical way would be to use `text-align: center` ofcourse, but for *semantic purposes* i'd like to include a more satisfying solution.

[Use `flexbox` to go for exact horizontal](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/centering_vertically_horizontally.htm) and vertical styling

```
ul {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have worked out the answer for you below, this involves using base code HTML5 & CSS3 to form the code required:

```css
ul {
  width: 580px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 2px solid black;
 }

li {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 80px;
 }
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>ITEM 1</li>
 <li>ITEM 2</li>
 <li>ITEM 3</li>
 <li>ITEM 4</li>
</ul>

<br>

<ul>
 <li>ITEM 1</li>
 <li>ITEM 2</li>
 <li>ITEM 3</li>
 <li>ITEM 4</li>
 <li>ITEM 5</li>
</ul>
```